# When I want to use the turtle.goto() command there is an error message that says "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'goto'"

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is my code; I have already imported turtle and the values in the array have been calculated. The data type of the values is numpy.float64. Why do i get this error message `"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'goto'"` All variables are defined, i have no clue what the problem is! Please Help
I imported turtle as t

```
for i in range(tt+2):
    t.goto(horizontal[i], height[i])
```

Comment: Where is your assignment of t?

Comment: `t` isn't a turtle, so you can't call `goto` on it.

Comment: Can you show us what `t` is.

Comment: where is `t` assigned to?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that i imported turtle as t

Comment: Are you using `t` as a variable elsewhere? If yes the try `import turtle as ttl` and then `ttl.goto ...`

Comment: @JackHayton: can you show us a small piece of code that we can run on our own computers that has this error? Right now, it looks like there is some line of code between `import turtle as t` and what you've shown us that is causing your issue.

Comment: Yes I have used t as a variable elsewhere, i just tried to import turtle without the "as t" and it works! It must because t was reassigned to something else. Thank you

Comment: I am new to programming, sorry for this unclear question, its solved now though, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Will do, can only accept in 3 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `t` as a variable somewhere else in your program and thus you are getting an error

Try

```
import turtle
for i in range(tt+2):
    turtle.goto(horizontal[i], height[i])
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

`t` is likely not a `Turtle` instance, but an `int`